# Google Analytics Content Experiments: Regular expressions and backreference

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-experiments, content-experiments

I need to setup the experiment as follows:

**Original:** www.domain.com/original/x?param=something

**Variation:** www.domain.com/variation/x?param=something_else

Where x is variable and needs to be carried forward to the variation on the redirect.

Is Regular Expression and Backreferences supported by Content Experiment, so that I can do something like:

**Original:** www.domain.com/original/(.*)?param=something

**Variation:** www.domain.com/variation/$1?param=something_else

Is there a way I can setup the experiment URLs, the way that I need it to work?

Answer (score 0):

if your parameters have the same name, don't use the `Regex` for it. Just:

```
1) Replace("original","variation");
2) Replace("something","something_else");
```

Answer (score 0):

@hwnd Thats sounds promising, however, I'm not sure what 'Search' and 'Replace' you were referring to.

I was referring to setting up Content Experiment as the title suggested.

Are you saying that I can set up the experiment as follows?

Original Page

Web page to experiment

www.domain.com/original/([\d+])?param=something

Variation 1

Web page to experiment

www.domain.com/variation/\1?param=somethingelse

Is this how I should set it?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the 2 options of backreferencing ( as suggested by @hwnd ) in the variation URLs:

- \1
- $A1

In both cases, the experiments managed to redirect to the variation URL however, both cases were unable to carry over the regex matched group value (*x*) to the variationi URL.

That means that in order to be able to do Google Experiment, we would have to change the URL format by moving *x* to the query string. :(